# rearrange text in a Table field - MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a Table in MS Access named Suche and it has a Field named Ver. The values under this field are in the pattern **03741277LV03** . I want to know if there is a possibility in Access to rearrange the values as **03LV-03741277** as we can do in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update <TABLE_NAME>
SET <column_name> = RIGHT(column_name,2) + LEFT(RIGHT(column_name,4),2) + '-' + LEFT(column_name, 8)
WHERE <some_condition>
```

Comment: When I use the above code I get only -03741277 . I can't find any error in the code but I am not sure where is it going wrong. Do you have any idea?

Comment: does your column have any spaces on the end? if so, we should also trim it

Comment: yes. it works now when I update it with Replace(Column," ","");. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Yes.... CONACTENATE (**&**) and **MID** functions will help you to achieve the results. Reference are provided below.

[MID function](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/mid.php)

[Concatenate](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/concat.php)

Comment: That's just a comment - which doesn't work in Access.